# C# Design Problem Regarding Data Encapsulation

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, encapsulation

I have four classes:
1: one that owns the data
2: another that updates the data
3: third that is informed by the first about certain changes of the data
4: last that reads certain properties from the first class

I do not want any other class but the second to be able to update the data.
So what is the best deign patter to use here ?

**More on the problem:**
1st class is called Schema and it holds a counter of how many instances using that Schema there is.
2nd class is called Factory and it creates/deletes these instances, hence I need to update Schema instance counters and create new Schema objects when necessary.
3rd class is called Config and it holds various shared configurations including information about each new Schema object.
4th class is called View and it simply views Schema information.
Schema objects can be accessed by ID as they are held in a static list.

Comment: What is the reason a second class and only that class can change properties of the first class. Why isn't that code in the first class(and so taking care of encapsulation?

Answer (score 3):

Switch from procedural code to object-oriented code and merge the two first classes into a single class that has both data and behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very abstract description of your scenario, and makes it very difficult to see your problem and what you want to do.

When talking about 'oop', you would typically have a single class that describes an object.  In your case, your object is 'the data'.  Therefore your first class should be the data and encapsulate any operations on that data.

Classes describe objects - they are not collections of functions. It sounds like your second class is simply a collection of functions.

You will need to further describe your situation because it really doesn't explain much at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for the pattern (maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952933/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-observer-pattern) ?) name but basically you have:

1: one that owns the data (fire events on data changes)

2: another that updates the data

The 3rd class is basically your "client code" - code which consumes other code (in this case class 1) can be any class which subscribes to the events of the first class

**EDIT**: I think what you are describing might be close to the [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a design pattern here. Just some principles.

Idea is simple:

object is defined by its behavior
  object modifies only state of itself
  object guards its state

```
public class SecondClass{
  public FirstClass First{get;private set;}
  public ThirdClass Third{get; private set;}
  public void DoSomething(){
    First.Something++;
    Second.NotifySomethingHasBeenDone();
  }
}
```

If relation between 2nd and 3rd class isn't that direct, You might want to use events for notifying:

```
public class SecondClass{
  public FirstClass First{get;private set;}
  public void DoSomething(){
    First.Something++;
    RaiseEvent<SomethingHasBeenDone>(this);
  }
}

public class ThirdClass:IHandles<SomethingHasBeenDone>{
  public void Handle(SomethingHasBeenDone @event){
    MessageBox("First has {0} something".With(@event.First.Something));
  }
}
```