# javascript mediator vs observer

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern, mediator

First I want to say I have googled `javascript mediator vs observer` and read almost ten links.

Also I search in statckoverflow and I got this [Mediator Vs Observer Object-Oriented Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226479/mediator-vs-observer) and 
[mediator-vs-observer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134432/mediator-vs-observer).

However I still do not have  clear understand about the difference between them.

So I wonder if someone can explain them more clearly?

Maybe a live example. :)

Thanks.

---

I tried to create an example, is this a pattern of mediator?

code:

```
var EventMediator = {
    publish: function (target, message) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
        var msgs = target.messages || [];
        for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            var msg = msgs[i];
            msg.callback.apply(msg.context, args);
        }
    },
    register: function (target, message, fn) {
        target.messages = target.messages || [];
        target.messages.push({
            context: target,
            callback: fn
        });
    }
};

var t1 = {name: 'kk'};
var t2 = {name: 'gg'};

EventMediator.register(t1, "nameChanged", function () {
    console.info("t1 name chagned");
});
EventMediator.publish(t1, "nameChanged");
```

Here I want to know if the `Mediator` should know about the exist of the object who trigger the message?

Comment: Check my answer for more example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226479/mediator-vs-observer-object-oriented-design-patterns/51350834#51350834

Answer (score 6):

**Observer pattern**: the observed object *manages its own list* of observers (aka listeners) which must be notified when a certain event happens.

**Mediator pattern**: the observed object is *not aware* of the list of its observers, there is an external entity that makes the mapping between observed objects and observers.

Comment: Sounds like a mix between both patterns: there is a central mediator entity but it stores observers in the targets instead of keeping the mapping in itself.