# ThreeJS: Is it possible to play certain animations in order?

Tags: three.js

I have written several methods does separate animations in my scene. However, I want to have each animation play after the previous one is finished.

Like if I have 2 different animation methods like `moveObject1(x)` and `moveObject2(x)` where x is the amount the object will move, how could I tell if moveObject1 is done moving x amount to run moveObject2?

Comment: You must either fire each function as a callback function once your completion condition is met or consider using some advanced libraries like [tween.js](http://www.createjs.com/tweenjs) that can help with sequencing.

Comment: Tween is good, also maybe you want to read on mediator pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417547/observer-pattern-vs-mediator-pattern might help to organize your code.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Thank you for the response! Would there be any examples that use tween.js to call the animations in order?

Comment: Well, google is your friend here. :)

Comment: @AnuragSrivasta Okay, I'll look into that then! Wondering if it can also work for more complex animations, like simultaneous rotation and position changes?

Comment: Oh yes, it is quite an advanced library, search for examples of tweenjs with threejs.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I've been searching for a while in tweenjs but now I'm wondering if it's chaining method can use existing animation functions that I made? I see that you could do simple one's like changing the position. But what if you already have complex animation methods that you want to call in order?

Comment: Added a basic example as an answer, see if it helps you.