# mediator design pattern implemented in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, mediator

is this correct way to implement Mediator design pattern in java ?

```
public class chat {
    public static void showMesg(Color c , String msg){
    System.out.println(new Date().toString() +" "+c + " " + msg +" ");

    }
}
```

then i call the "ShowMesg" method in method Draw of red class

```
public class Red implements Color {
      public void draw() {
          chat.showMesg(this, "Hey this is Red :D");
      System.out.println("Red color");
      }
```

Comment: No. "in java" would require you to follow the naming conventions for the language. That's notwithstanding the pattern implementation.

Comment: What makes you think it is not?

Answer (score 3):

No. You did not implement [Mediator](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-mediator)  pattern (courtesy:dzone article by  *James Sugrue*) properly.

Structure:

[image]

The **Mediator** defines the interface for communication between *Colleague* objects.

The *ConcreteMediator* implements the *Mediator* interface and coordinates communication between *Colleague* objects.

It is aware of all the *Colleagues* and their purpose with regards to inter communication.The *ConcreteColleague* communicates with other colleagues through the **Mediator**.

Your example does not use Mediator pattern at all. You have tight coupling between your objects.

Have a look at code example in below post for better understanding:

[Mediator Vs Observer Object-Oriented Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226479/mediator-vs-observer-object-oriented-design-patterns/38833360#38833360)