# Observer pattern vs Event Bus message approach

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture

I've been looking at MVC implementations and Event-bus closely.

Why not use Event-bus instead of Observer Pattern to implement a MVC application?

For example, lets say I have two classes `Model` and `View`, In typical observer pattern it would be:

```
public class Model implements Subject { ... }

public class View implements Observer { ... }
```

Instead, what is the benefit/drawback of an approach using [green robot event bus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) or any other Event-bus?

It would be something like:

```
public class Model {
   private int field = 0; 

   void someFunctionNowTriggerStateChange() {
     this.field = field + 1;
     ...EventBus.getDefault().post(this); //pass itself as the event
   }
}

public class View {

  @Subscribe onModelUpdated(Model model) {
    updateTextLabel(model);
    //other model updates
  }   
}
```

What are the issues (if any) of using the EventBus to implement MVC vs typical Observer?

Answer (score 7):

EventBus implements publisher subscriber pattern,

> EventBus is an open-source library for Android and Java using the publisher/subscriber pattern for loose coupling.

The [difference from observer pattern](https://hackernoon.com/observer-vs-pub-sub-pattern-50d3b27f838c) is that publisher is **loosely coupled** from subscribers

> publisher and subscriber don’t know about the existence of one another. There is a third component, called broker or message broker or event bus, which is known by both the publisher and subscriber, which filters all incoming messages and distributes them accordingly. In other words, pub-sub is a pattern used to communicate messages between different system components without these components knowing anything about each other’s identity.

One advantage is that Publisher/Subscriber pattern can be normally/easier to be implemented in an asynchronous way because having a third component, broker, assist to implement asynchronous behavior, because execution becomes loosely coupled

Another advantage, because Publisher/Subscriber pattern is loosely coupled, it will be more intuitive/easier to implement also multiple subscribers

> Observer pattern is mostly implemented in a synchronous way, i.e. the Subject calls the appropriate method of all its observers when some event occurs. The Publisher/Subscriber pattern is mostly implemented in an asynchronous way (using message queue).

If you don't need (and won't need) such broker, you are safe to use Observer pattern, which will make your code smaller and simpler

[image]

Comment: @flakes updated with quote, it will be more natural/easy to implement asynchronous behavior when it's loosely coupled

Comment: I would still add the reason as to why it's easier. It may be the case that most pub-sub systems allow asynchronous subscription, but as the answer is written it's an unjustified claim. Maybe a note about separations of concerns.

Comment: @flakes using a third component, broker, assist to implement asynchronous behavior because execution becomes loosely coupled

Comment: What about having multiple subjects? In observer pattern I can only have one subject. With event bus however, I can have events for update in state of many different subjects. Isn't this an advantage/benefit of using an Event Bus over Observer pattern?

Comment: @eansn You have a point, but multiple subjects with one observer can also be called observer 
 pattern see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952933/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-observer-pattern

Comment: In that case, implementing with the same `update()` method for all subjects in the observer it will be difficult and nasty with casting to see which of the subjects have changed, don't you think?

Comment: @eansn update *Another advantage, because Publisher/Subscriber pattern is loosely coupled, it will be more intuitive/easier to implement also multiple subscribers*